# How to break transpose at specific rows depending on the cell content?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

So I am working on this excel/spreadsheet project where I have to achieve:

**FROM: (assuming that Fruit is in cell A1)**
[image: I have this]

TO: (Assuming that Fruit Summary is in Cell I1)
[image: I want to achieve this]

Comment: In these few days, what have you tried? `SUMIFS()`, `COUNTIFS()`? Also are you looking for an Excel solution, or Google Spreadsheets solution?

Comment: Have you tried pivot tables?

Comment: I tried SUMIFS() but couldnt figure it out. This worked like a charm though: =QUERY (A1:G11,"select A, Count (A),Sum(G),sum(D) group by A")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
=QUERY (A1:G11,"select A, Count (A),Sum(G),sum(D) group by A")
```

Comment: Wow! You made it look so easy, Works like charm! Saved my butt Steve! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I answered -_- Steve only removed 4 spaces from my answer for formatting.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I am new here and didnt know how it showed. My bad, you answered anonymous!! Thank you! And steve thank you too for editing it.